# How to condense Yup "when" validations

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have several fields that are required if a single condition is true.  Is there a better way to condense this code to avoid repeating the `when` for all of these fields?

```
const requiredForDiffAddress = {
    is: false,
    then: Yup.string().required()
};

export const BillingAddressYupValidationSchemaShape = {
  useShippingAddress: Yup.boolean().default(true).required(),
  street: Yup.string()
      .when('useShippingAddress', requiredForDiffAddress),
  city: Yup.string()
      .when('useShippingAddress', requiredForDiffAddress),
  state: Yup.string()
      .when('useShippingAddress', requiredForDiffAddress),
  zipCode: Yup.string()
      .when('useShippingAddress', requiredForDiffAddress),
};
```

Or for a more realistic and involved sample

```
const buildRequiredForDiffAddress = requiredText => ({
    is: false,
    then: Yup.string().required(requiredText)
});

export const BillingAddressYupValidationSchemaShape = {
  useShippingAddress: Yup.boolean().default(true).required(),
  street1: Yup.string().when('useShippingAddress', 
      buildRequiredForDiffAddress("How will we know where to send your order?")),
  city: Yup.string().when('useShippingAddress', 
    buildRequiredForDiffAddress("What city do you live in?")),
  state: Yup.string().when('useShippingAddress',
    buildRequiredForDiffAddress("State please!")),
  zipCode: Yup.string().when('useShippingAddress', 
      buildRequiredForDiffAddress("Zip Code please!")),
};
```

Comment: That's a nice demonstration on why one should prefer just normal functions over chained methods: the former compose.

Comment: I think it's fine to have chained methods, you just need to be able to chain things directly, so something like `useShippingAddress: Yup.boolean().default(true).when(false, requiredAddressFieldsSchema)`

Comment: It's fine, but then you have problems like you have now

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for your comment.  It made me think about a more realistic example which makes things even more painful.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:** The solution posted in the question is probably the best way to handle fields that are required only when a condition is met based off the value of some other field*

**Extended Answer**

I've looked at this quite a bit after [messaging the creator of Yup](https://twitter.com/snekse/status/1064668232269864960).

He suggested

> extend mixed with a `requiredIf` method to encapsulate this sort of thing

I looked into what would be involved with that along with using some form of `lazy`.  The extension route seemed to be better than the lazy route, but in the end, I feel like what I have is probably the best solution.

I created this fairly detailed CodeSandbox is someone wants to take a stab and find a better solution.  I'll gladly change the accepted answer for this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/xk4r7nq9z

* *...and you want custom error messaging per field.  It seems as if you are okay w/ the default messaging, then the example posted may not be the simplest solution.*

Comment: This sandbox currently only works with Formik 1.5.+.  I haven't looked at what changed in 2.+ that breaks the sandbox.

Comment: Could you (or someone else) please post an example of a requiredIf method? I'm struggling with that right now and I don't think a new question would be the best way to go

Comment: @Alex this might help https://github.com/jquense/yup/pull/150/files#diff-a39772825a6753e21b910a44bde28402